# Ubuntu Installation-No Internet connection

Tags: networking, drivers, system-installation, usb, internet

I'm a new Linux user and this is my first time installing Ubuntu on my new machine I just built. Install is going great but now under the "Preparing to install Ubuntu" section, I can't connect to my home wifi to get the update.

Note: Router is on other side of house, so Ethernet is a no go. I'm using a Netgear Wireless N-300 USB adapter WNA3100 to connect. I was using a installed USB version of Ubuntu on the same machine with a different USB adapter which is no longer working.

Could it be a driver issue? Or is my new Netgear adapter not formated right for Linux (A friend told me I had to format it.)

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your friend must have misunderstood it for a storage device; please add the output of `lsusb`, `iwconfig`, `lsmod` and `lshw -C network` as an [edit] to your question. (Open a terminal, execute each command and copy-paste the output)

Comment: I'm still in the installation window, how can I run terminal? Or is it ok to finish the install without internet connection?

Comment: To open a terminal you can use default keyboard shortcut of `Ctrl+Alt+T` or just move your mouse to `Activities` (top-left corner) and start typing _terminal_, or browse application launchers to find it

Comment: To the_Seppi, how I can post them if I dont have connection?

Comment: Dunno... paste it into a text file, put it on an USB stick and take it to a device with internet access ;) Be creative!

Comment: Or if you got a smartphone that you can use as tethered network adaper, put it on the computer and get the updates via your phone's WiFi (In Android: Settings->Wireless and Network->More...->Tethering&Portable hotspop, in iOS: Settings->Personal Hotspot)

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the updates, you can download them later.

Comment: Is the router totally out of reach or can you use a cable if you need to dl new drivers for your wifi adapter?

Comment: Yes the router is our of reach and I don't have a cable that can reach. But I do have a laptop that is connected to wifi. Could I use that to find the drivers for the adapter?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/504884)

Comment: @Raphael: I disagree. This is the exact advice I would give to a Ubuntu novice with networking problems during system installation.

Comment: No internet on installation - great problems and many man-days to fix... without internet on installation, you have to do everything on your own, install all basic packages, drivers, even commands on your own - without internet... for netowrk driver you will need "build-essentials" package, but to install it you need "make" command, and that command needs many other packages and those other packages just in order to get your internet and start to install all that you even not imagined you would need... and face after that many problems every month due to some driver or inner thing missing ...