# Installation without internet

Tags: system-installation

What will happen if I install Ubuntu without internet connection. Actually, my internet connection is very poor. I hardly get a speed of 150kb/s. Will I miss some important update if I do so. Please suggest me.

Comment: There is no problems with offline installation. Maybe some interface languages won't install. You can do it later.

Comment: How to install them after system installation?

Comment: Using system settings. Anyway you'll need internet to download them.

Comment: Also, if you have no Internet, you cannot apply security updates when they are released by the Security Team.  Or kernel updates, or other bugfix updates.  WHich is something you'll have to consider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Installation-No Internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712862/ubuntu-installation-no-internet-connection)

Answer (score 1):

You need an iso file with a current version of Ubuntu. And you need a tool to install Ubuntu into a USB pendrive or DVD disk. You need internet access for that unless you have them already or can borrow from a friend or colleague.

But after that **you can do the installation locally without any connection to the internet**.

After the installation there might be problems because the built-in linux drivers do not work with some piece of hardware, for example graphics chip or wifi chip, or as you ask in a comment, you may want a language, that is not bundled with the iso file. If this happens, you need an internet connection to get the relevant software.

A new language can be installed like this in Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS:

- Click on the icon at right top corner of the screen
- Next, click on the symbol with tools
- Next, if necessary click on `<` icon in the left top corner of the window until you come to the basic Settings window
- Next, Select 'Region & Language' and I think you can navigate to select your language.